# How to fetch data with sum and group by in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I have tow tables (donation and members) i want to fetch member name form member table date and amount from donation table with group by member id form doantion table when i call the function it gives and error like (SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'donatensupport.donations.donation_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `donations`.*, `members`.*, sum(amount) as amount from `donations` inner join `members` on `donations`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` group by `member_id`)) i google it several times but i did not find any solution any body help thank in advance

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
       $donation = DB::table('donations')
            ->join('members', 'donations.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
            ->select('donations.*','members.*', DB::raw('sum(amount) as amount'))
            ->groupBy('member_id')
            ->get();
       return view('donation.index', compact('donation'));
}
```

**Donation Model**

```
public function member() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Member','member_id', 'id');
}
```

**Member Model**

```
public function donation() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the models?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use donations.* and members.* in select when you are using group by.
In these case you must set explictically the column name you need  and make sure that the column name not involved  in aggegation function are  mentioned  in group by clause

```
   $donation = DB::table('donations')
        ->join('members', 'donations.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
        ->select('donations.member_id as member_id','members.name as name', DB::raw('sum(amount) as amount'))
        ->groupBy('member_id','name')
        ->get();
        return view('donation.index', compact('donation'));
```

Comment: I agree it's best to compute as much as you can in sql rather than php.  However, I wanted to mention that laravel collections support similar operations, and the line between sql and php can be blurred in a very expressive way that is easy to read months down the road or for the next developer. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections Depending on how much data there is - collections could be more straight forward and maintainable.

Comment: when i add date column it show the date also but the result is not the one which i want

Comment: if the error is gone then  you have found the reason for error  .. for " the result you want "  seems another qestion to me

Comment: there is date column in my donation table also so how to fetch date too with amount and name when i add date column the sum is not working

Comment: you have error ?   the same error in your question?